# How do I make an included unmanaged enum public in C++/CLI?

Tags: c++-cli

I'm writing a managed wrapper for [libdwarf](https://www.prevanders.net/dwarf.html). One of the header files, `dwarf_names_enum.h`, contains hundreds of enumeration members generated at compile-time. I'd like to use one of those enumerations for a property in my managed wrapper. However, in `dwarf_names_enum.h`, the enums don't have `public` in front of them. How do I make the enums public without modifying libdwarf?

Comment: There is no convenient way to do this.  Managed and unmanaged enums are distinct kind of types and treated very differently by the compiler.  If you need them exposed to managed code written in, say, C# then you have to declare a new type.  Yes, painful.  Only converting to `int` is easy.

Comment: @HansPassant - Mind adding that as an answer? Then I can accept it. Based on what you said, I guess I can make a pre-build step in my managed wrapper which constructs a new header file based on `dwarf_names_enum.h`.